# JavaScript Privilege Limitation

Tags: javascript, privileges

I am using a partner javascript on my website. 
We are adding it by importing by  tag.

I wish to limit the access capabilities of the use of this javascript.
How can I manage it's access to different site location and data?

**Edit:** Additional info 
(note: my question is more security handling):

adding script for example:

```
<script async src='http://www.somewhere.com/somefunctionality.js'></script>
<script>
func1('param1', 'param2');
func2('param3', 'param4');
</script>
```

The js script is available in the basic site template, so it will available easily in all the site.(e.g.  calling it's functions)

But, I wan't to limit his ability to access some areas/data of the site. or perform any unauthorized actions. 
Without moving it. 
is it possible?

Thanks, 
Js

Comment: you'll need to supply a LOT more information than that

Comment: In what way do you want to limit it?

Comment: Edited the question for adding more data.  
The question is a security concern of how to control external JS and site developers.

Comment: @user3478489 still doesn't answer what needs to be accessed and what not. Since the script is literally in your page, the script owner can write anything in it to access the content of the page.  If you can give a realistic example. It will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can run the external library inside of Google Caja. It's designed exactly for this purpose.